# How to change " asp-action=" with your selected Viewbag .Net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to change the "asp-action= ", unfortunately I could not find anything on the internet...

Currently I am working with a ViewBag where I can select a value from that list.

What I want is: I want to put that selected value from the ViewBag in the "asp-action= ( here ) "

[Image of my index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YixPh.png) 
[Image of my Post method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myr4A.png)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Parser" asp-action= "PostDrone">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p> 
        <select  asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.listofitems ))"></select> 
        <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>
```

For example:

I want the "asp-action=" have the string value "PostSchoen" if I selected PostSchoen from the viewbag selectlist

I hope it is understandable what i said

Comment: Also, your SELECT element selection will be also submitted to the server.use `asp-for` so that it generates the name for your view model property and you can use that in your server side to do different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wants to do it should doing by client side development with JS

But you have three ways:

1) You can change it by using JS

here an example with Jquery

need add it to onReady function this will change action to option val

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $("select").change(function (){
          //set form action to option val or get to whatever you need
          $(this).closest("form").attr("action",$(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

2) Send data to one contoller method then switch it by your select or other options

change in view

```
  <select name="typeOfUploading" asp-items="@(new
 SelectList(@ViewBag.listofitems ))"></select>
```

change in controller

```
     PostDrone(List<IFromFile> files, string typeOfUploading) 
{ 
//and use typeOfUploading this will be selected value from your select list 
}
```

3) Firstly provide for user this data send choise, that generate him correct view with needed action

Comment: I have no experience with Jquery, is there no other option to make this work ? :(

Comment: Thanks tho, but I have no idea how to implement the second or third options. :s I really appreciate the time that you spend to help me.

Comment: @Ogieeeeee, just add my script from first way to your view and check it

Comment: Use `change` event. Also `closest('form')` than `parent`.

Comment: Where do I put it exactly int the view?

Comment: @Shyju, i change it thanks, Ogieeeeee  check updated script

Comment: @Ogieeeeee i have not discord=(

Comment: @itikhomi damn :(

Comment: 2) Send data to one contoller method then switch it by your select or other options.  I'm gonna try to do this...  since  they tell me to use javascript which i have no experience with.

Comment: @itikhomi Dude, I think this is exactly what i wanted!!!!!!!!!!! For now I think it is working because it is not executing the loop if it is not the value in the viewbag.. I love you man.. I can't fix my code today but maybe tomorrow if I think that this program does what i think i do! MAN  HOW YOU ARE SO GOOD!?

Comment: @itikhomi Finished my code today and it's working! Thanks dude I was searching for this so long. Long live the community !